# GetCultureInfo defaults

Tags: c#, multilingual

I am using the following to return CultureInfo.

```
CultureInfo info = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("it-IT");
```

My question is, from where does it get the values returned? Are these built into the OS / Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are taken from the OS, though you can create custom ones.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures.aspx):

> Setting types to the AllCultures value returns all neutral and specific cultures, cultures **installed in the Windows system**, **and custom cultures created by the user**.

Highlights are mine.